# ¿Como llenar las columnas de una matriz A que estan en una matriz B y faltan en A?

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo dos matrices `P` y `Q` y quiero hacer un cálculo de matriz `P*Q.T`. Entonces necesito el mismo numero de columnas. `P` tenga m_p subscriber y n_p hashtags y m_q con m_p publicidades (que llamamos "eclipse") por `Q`. Ambas tienen id para diferenciar subscriber, eclipse y hashtag. Sin embargo cuando un usuario no ha relaciones con un hashtag, no aparece el hastag en las columnas de `P`.

Entonces como llenar las columnas de `P` con las de `Q` que faltan sobre `hashtag_id` (pero con 0)?

Aquí esta como fueron constructado `P` y `Q` :

```
    try:
        conn = psycopg2.connect(**params)
        cur = conn.cursor()
            cur = conn.cursor()
            cur.execute("""
    SELECT COUNT(swipe.eclipse_id), subscriber_hashtag.hashtag_id,subscriber_hashtag.subscriber_id  FROM subscriber_hashtag
      -- join para que las publicidades/eclipses que gusta un usuarios están vinculadas con las de la tabla de correspondencia con los hashtag
      INNER JOIN eclipse_hashtag ON eclipse_hashtag.hashtag_id = subscriber_hashtag.hashtag_id
      -- join para que los usuarios  están vinculadas con los de la tabla de correspondencia con los hashtag
      LEFT OUTER JOIN swipe ON subscriber_hashtag.subscriber_id = swipe.subscriber_id
      -- recobremos los "me gusta"
      WHERE swipe.state= 3 OR swipe.state = 6 or swipe.state=9
        GROUP BY subscriber_hashtag.hashtag_id,subscriber_hashtag.subscriber_id
          ORDER BY subscriber_hashtag.hashtag_id,subscriber_hashtag.subscriber_id DESC;
          """)
            p = cur.fetchall()
            listado_p = [{"count": elem[0], "hashtag_id": elem[1], "subscriber_id": elem[2]} for elem in p]
            print(listado_p[0]['count'])

            cur.execute("""
    SELECT COUNT(eclipse_hashtag.eclipse_id), eclipse_hashtag.hashtag_id,eclipse_hashtag.eclipse_id FROM eclipse_hashtag
        GROUP BY eclipse_hashtag.hashtag_id, eclipse_hashtag.eclipse_id
          ORDER BY eclipse_hashtag.hashtag_id,eclipse_hashtag.eclipse_id ASC;
        """)
            q = cur.fetchall()
            listado_q = [{"count": elem[0], "hashtag_id": elem[1], "eclipse_id": elem[2]} for elem in q]
            print(listado_q[0]['count'])

# recuperamos los valores brutos
df_p = pd.DataFrame(listado_p)
df_q = pd.DataFrame(listado_q)

# sustituimos NaN con 0
df_p['hashtag_id'] = df_p['hashtag_id'].fillna(0).astype(int)
df_q['hashtag_id'] = df_q['hashtag_id'].fillna(0).astype(int)

# creamos matrices :
df_p2 = df_p.pivot(index='subscriber_id', columns='hashtag_id', values='count')
df_q2 = df_q.pivot(index='eclipse_id', columns='hashtag_id', values='count')

P = np.array(P)
Q = np.array(Q)
```

Y las dimensiones de las matrices :

```
print "(subscriber,hastag) : ",df_p2.shape
print "(eclipse,hashtag) : ",df_q2.shape

(subscriber,hastag) :  (21, 157)
(eclipse,hashtag) :  (618, 364)
```

---

Para el ejemplo minimo y verificable, podemos utilisar :

```
--- df_p ---
    count  hashtag_id  subscriber_id
0      22         321            172
1      44         321            161
2      25         322            172
3       6         323            172
4      32         325            172
5      26         328            161
6      48         329            172
7      96         329            161
8      14         335            172
```

y

```
    ---  df_q ---
      count  eclipse_id  hashtag_id
0         1        6521         321
1         1        6606         321
2         1        6609         321
3         1        6617         321
4         1        6649         321
5         1        6911         321
6         1        6914         321
7         1        7001         321
8         1        7004         321
9         1        7120         321
10        1        9534         321
11        1       10442         321
12        1       10452         321
13        1       10458         321
14        1       10462         321
15        1       10479         321
16        1       10490         321
17        1       10506         321
18        1       10523         321
19        1       10573         321
20        1       10593         321
21        1       10711         321
22        1        6521         322
23        1        6606         322
24        1        6609         322
...     ...         ...         ...
2182      1       11175        2272
2183      1       11176        2272
2184      1       11177        2272
2185      1       11178        2272
2186      1       11179        2272
2187      1       11180        2272
2188      1       11181        2272
2189      1       11229        2470
2190      1       11230        2470
2191      1       11231        2470
2192      1       11232        2470
2193      1       11233        2470
2194      1       11234        2470
2195      1       11235        2470
2196      1       11236        2470
2197      1       11237        2470
2198      1       11238        2470
2199      1       11239        2470
2200      1       11240        2470
2201      1       11241        2470
2202      1       11242        2470
2203      1       11243        2470
2204      1       11244        2470
2205      1       11245        2470
2206      1       11246        2470
2207      1       11247        2470
2208      1       11248        2470
2209      1       11249        2533
2210      1       11250        2533
2211      1       11251        2533
```

Podemos ver que faltan hastags en `df_p`

---

Aqui esta : una pregunta subyacente. Como hacer dos reindización ? Una sobre las columnas y una sobre las lineas ? Aqui falta en `df_p` `subcriber_id` de `df_n`.

```
--- df_n ---
    count  eclipse_id  subscriber_id
0       1     11265.0            150
1      12     10453.0            150
2       1     11267.0            150
3       1     11266.0            150
4       1     11270.0            156
5       1     11267.0            156
6      17     10453.0            156
7       1     11266.0            156
8       1     11269.0            161
9       1         NaN            161
```

He hecho :

```
df_p2_r = df_p2.reindex(index = df_n2.index)
```

pero esto cancela la reindización anterior : `df_p2_r = df_p2.reindex(columns = df_q2.columns)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si te he entendido bién, tu problema es que `df_q2` tiene columnas (`'hashtag_id'`) que no existen en `df_p2`. Necesitas agregar estas columnas y rellenarlas con ceros para que ambos dataframes tengan el mismo número de columnas.

Si presuponemos que todas las columnas de `df_p2` existen en `df_q2`, pero que hay columnas de `df_q2` que no están en `df_p2`, entonces solo hace falta un reindexado de las columnas de `df_p2` usando las de `df_q2` para solucionarlo:

```
df_p2 = df_p2.reindex(columns = df_q2.columns)
```

Creando un ejemplo podemos verlo:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

listado_q = [{"count": 21, "hashtag_id":321 , "eclipse_id":306},
             {"count": 23, "hashtag_id":400 , "eclipse_id":306},
             {"count": 35, "hashtag_id":321 , "eclipse_id":330},
             {"count": 95, "hashtag_id":421 , "eclipse_id":403},
             {"count": 21, "hashtag_id":841 , "eclipse_id":515},
             {"count": 14, "hashtag_id":351 , "eclipse_id":684},
             {"count": 13, "hashtag_id":985 , "eclipse_id":801}]


listado_p = [{"count": 17, "hashtag_id":321 , "subscriber_id":142},
             {"count": 13, "hashtag_id":321 , "subscriber_id":345},
             {"count": 19, "hashtag_id":421 , "subscriber_id":467},
             {"count": 23, "hashtag_id":841 , "subscriber_id":175}]


# recuperamos los valores brutos
df_p = pd.DataFrame(listado_p)
df_q = pd.DataFrame(listado_q)

# creamos matrices :
df_p2 = df_p.pivot(index='subscriber_id', columns='hashtag_id', values='count')
df_q2 = df_q.pivot(index='eclipse_id', columns='hashtag_id', values='count')


df_p2_r = df_p2.reindex(columns = df_q2.columns) # <<< Reindexamos

df_p2.fillna(0, inplace=True)
df_p2_r.fillna(0, inplace=True)
df_q2.fillna(0, inplace=True)


print '-'*50, '\ndf_p2 original\n', '-'*50
print df_p2, '\n'
print '-'*50, '\ndf_p2 reindexado\n', '-'*50
print df_p2_r, '\n'
print '-'*50, '\ndf_p2\n', '-'*50
print(df_q2), '\n'
```

**Salida:**

> ```
> -------------------------------------------------- 
> df_p2 original
> --------------------------------------------------
> hashtag_id      321   421   841
> subscriber_id                  
> 142            17.0   0.0   0.0
> 175             0.0   0.0  23.0
> 345            13.0   0.0   0.0
> 467             0.0  19.0   0.0 
>
> -------------------------------------------------- 
> df_p2 reindexado
> --------------------------------------------------
> hashtag_id      321  351  400   421   841  985
> subscriber_id                                 
> 142            17.0  0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0
> 175             0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0  23.0  0.0
> 345            13.0  0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0
> 467             0.0  0.0  0.0  19.0   0.0  0.0 
>
> -------------------------------------------------- 
> df_p2
> --------------------------------------------------
> hashtag_id   321   351   400   421   841   985
> eclipse_id                                    
> 306         21.0   0.0  23.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
> 330         35.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
> 403          0.0   0.0   0.0  95.0   0.0   0.0
> 515          0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  21.0   0.0
> 684          0.0  14.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
> 801          0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  13.0
> ```

No se si esto resuelve tu problema o no. Si no es este tu problema intenta expresarlo mejor y, sobre todo, sería muy útil que agregaras un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), dado que no podemos reproducir el problema al venir los datos de consultas a base de datos. Simplemente crea un ejemplo reproducible que mustre tu problema y la salida que esperas tal y como he hecho yo en esta respuesta.

Comment: Mucahs gracias, voy a agregar un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable. ¿Sabes como reindexar columnas de una df con las de una  primera DF y las columnas con una otra ?

Comment: He hecho :

`df_p2_r = df_p2.reindex(index = df_n2.index)`
pero esto cancela la reindización anterior : `df_p2_r = df_p2.reindex(columns = df_q2.columns)`

Comment: Ha, he hecho `df_p2_r = df_p2.reindex(index = df_n2.index,columns=...)` y funciona. ;) Muchas gracias !